# How to disable "private mount namespace" (sandboxing) with the Nix package manager?

Tags: root, sandbox, nix, linux-namespaces

I'm trying to use nix on repl.it. I'm using static-nix from https://matthewbauer.us/blog/static-nix.html. If I run the following code:

```
mkdir -p "$HOME/.cache/nix/"
curl https://matthewbauer.us/nix > "$HOME/.cache/nix/nix.exe"
cat "$HOME/.cache/nix/nix.exe" | bash -s run --no-sandbox --store "$HOME/.cache/nix/store" -f channel:nixpkgs-unstable bash graphviz -c sh -c 'dot --help'
```

I get this error:

```
error: setting up a private mount namespace: Operation not permitted
```

I tried `--no-sandbox`, `--option sandbox false` and `--option build-use-sandbox false`, none of these have any effect on the error.

This is executed as non-root on a machine for which it is not possible for me to change kernel settings.

Here's a REPL reproducing the issue (it runs for a short while before displaying the error): https://repl.it/@suzannesoy/AgonizingWittyCoding#main.sh

Comment: This is most likely needed for `--store`

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out… I was using `--store` precisely because I don't have root access… if root is needed to use `--store`, I'm stuck in a loop :) . I thought Nix would rebuild everything as needed using a different --prefix, instead of trying to bind mount the store to /nix/store… IIRC that was the behaviour a while ago :-/

Comment: `--store` (that is, unrestricted user namespaces) does not need root on mainline Linux, but apparently on that platform it does. To outright change the store path prefix, I believe you have to rebuild Nix from source.

Comment: You might also be interested in https://discourse.nixos.org/t/nix-portable-nix-static-permissionless-install-free-pre-configured/11719